# How to get variables from radio buttons with multiple variables

Tags: function, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, parameter-passing

I have a program that uses Python tkinter to make radio buttons. I have 3 different variables , and each variable can be selected by selecting one out of many inputs which are specific to each variable (meaning there are like 5 inputs per variable, for example)

for example

```
radio1 = Radiobutton(someframe, text='somevalue', value=1, variable=thismyvar)
radio2 = Radiobutton(someframe, text='somevalue2', value=2, variable=thismyvar)
radio3 = Radiobutton(someframe, text='somevalue3', value=3, variable=thismyvar)
```

Then repeat this 2 more times for variable=thismyvar2 and variable=thismyvar3.

I then have a function that will submit the variable values into a form. I was wondering how to pass it to that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `thismyvar` is an instance of a tkinter `StringVar` or `IntVar`<sup>1</sup>, you need to call the `get` method of the var:

```
print("the value is: %s" % thismyvar.get())
```

<sup>1</sup> If they aren't, they need to be<sup>2</sup>. You can't use regular python variables.

<sup>2</sup> Literally speaking, they don't *need* to be, but using normal python variables requires a deep understanding of how tkinter is implemented, and it requires more code than if you used the tkinter variables. So just use the special tkinter variables.

Comment: Thanks! So if i wanted to save it into variables, would this work

Comment: getvariable1 = thisismyvar.get()

Comment: I also had another question, if lets say the text value of the radio is 'NEW' and the value is 1 

for example: 
somebutton = Radiobutton(someframe, text='NEW', value=1, variable=somevar)

and I wanted my selection of somebutton radios to return me back NEW, do i say value='NEW' instead of value=1?

Comment: thank you. I will try working on this. Do you know if the same rules apply for passing things? Like for example if my radiobutton gave me back a value and I wanted to use it in another function, do I have to pass it?